# How do I verify the uninstall of Grid Control and WebLogic?

Tags: oracle, oracle-grid-control

I installed Weblogic, the required patch and then Grid Control on a Linux (RHEL 5.5) server.  Unfortunately, my instructions did not have the -d64 tag to allow for 64 bit installation and I have to uninstall Grid Control and WebLogic then reinstall.

Their documentation for uninstalling leaves a lot to be desired and I had no less than 5 errors during the process.  My basic question is "How can I verify that I have deleted everything from WebLogic and Grid Control?"  This includes repositories.

Below is a basic overview of what I was given as instructions:

```
    1. <ORACLE_HOME>/bin/omsca delete -full   Errored
```

OMSCA-ERR:Admin server is down. Full option requires admin server up

/bin/emctl stop agent    No Error

1. /sysman/admin/emdrep/bin/RepManager  
    -action dropall -dbUser  -dbPassword
    -dbRole  -reposName  -reposPassword
    -mwHome  -mwOraHome  -oracleHome

Could not get above command to work at all

Ran the following:
DROP USER sysman CASCADE;
DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM setemviewusercontext;
DROP ROLE mgmt_user;
DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM mgmt_target_blackouts;
DROP USER mgmt_view;

emca -deconfig all db -repos drop

Manually delete the data files mgmt.dbf and mgmt_ecm_depot1.dbf from the Oracle home of the database.
Done

$/oui/bin/runInstaller -removeallfiles
Done

1. /etc/rc.d/ directory. For example, /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S98gcstartup.
   No clarity on which files to delete!
2. Note that instructions show no information on how to uninstall WLS!
   Ran:
   USER=oracle1 SID=emrep PATH=/home/oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/uninstall
   $./uninstall.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be really, *really* careful when mucking around in /etc/rc.d/; this is where your startup/shutdown programs live, so removing the wrong file will put you in to a world of hurt. (Unfortunately, I can't tell you which file is the one Oracle tends to use.)

Second, Oracle's uninstall instructions always leave a lot to be desired, as does the actual process, which leaves just about everything hanging around on the file system even when it isn't necessary anymore.

For removing Grid, IIRC (that is a *big* IF), I think you're in the clear -- pretty much exactly what I would have done. And, as to weblogic, same deal -- I'd have run the uninstall.sh and see what happens. I suppose you could nuke the entire directory at this point so that there'd be no chance of an old file coming back to bite you, so that'd be just about the only other thing I'd do.

Good luck with the re-install...

Comment: Thanks.  It won't let me click the up arrow so I went ahead and clicked the check box.  Hopefully that is beneficial to you for taking the time to answer.